# Laravel if request not empty add orWhere

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    if ($request->has('deleted')) {
        $assistants = Assistant::onlyTrashed()->where(1);
        if ($request->has('firstName'))
            $assistants = $assistants->orWhere('firstname', 'LIKE', $request->firstName.'%');
        if ($request->has('lastName'))
            $assistants = $assistants->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', $request->lastName.'%');
        if ($request->has('email'))
            $assistants = $assistants->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', $request->email.'%');
    } else {
        $assistants = Assistant::all()->where(1);
        if ($request->has('firstName'))
            $assistants = $assistants->orWhere('firstname', 'LIKE', $request->firstName.'%');
        if ($request->has('lastName'))
            $assistants = $assistants->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', $request->lastName.'%');
        if ($request->has('email'))
            $assistants = $assistants->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', $request->email.'%');
    }

    return $this->showAll($assistants);
}
```

I am trying to check if firstName, lastName or email is not empty, add to query with LIKE command.

But it returns an error :

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection::where(), 1 passed

in Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems.

1. `where(1)` is not a valid Query Builder call.  You also don't seem to need this.
2. You don't need to repeat all of these `request->has()` calls, put them below the if ... else ...
3. `Assistants::all()` will actually run a query and return all rows in a collection.  Use `Assistants::query()` to return a Query Builder instance.

Comment: Should i write raw query ? I couldnt find ::query()